# opennlp install - no suitable method found for train

Tags: java, maven, installation, java-7, opennlp

Hello I am trying to install opennlp on ubuntu. I have installed java 7, svn and maven 3.0.4. I have checked out the opennlp-trunk project based on the instructions on http://opennlp.apache.org/source-code.html.

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/opennlp/trunk/
```

Now I go into trunk/opennlp and run the install command

```
mvn clean install
```

and I get this error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4:17.074s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 05 16:46:08 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project opennlp-uima: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/ssriparasa-nlp/trunk/opennlp-uima/src/main/java/opennlp/uima/chunker/ChunkerTrainer.java:[206,41] error: no suitable method found for train(String,ObjectStream<ChunkSample>,int,int)
[ERROR] /home/ssriparasa-nlp/trunk/opennlp-uima/src/main/java/opennlp/uima/sentdetect/SentenceDetectorTrainer.java:[170,43] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project opennlp-uima: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the trunk is currently officially broken. The Apache Jenkins confirms the [build failure](https://builds.apache.org/job/OpenNLP/453/console). The OpenNLP developers have been notified.

*Disclosure: I am an Apache committer (not on OpenNLP though).*

Answer (score 1):

Build should be back to normal.

https://builds.apache.org/job/OpenNLP/454/console